# Do I include small amounts of interest on my taxes if they didn't send a 1099-INT?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099

One of my bank accounts earned $1.50 for the entire year.  Because the amount is under $10 they did not send a 1099-INT form.

Is this bank policy or IRS policy?  Does that $1.50 need to be reported?

I'm not worried about the difference that this small amount makes on my taxes bur rather what is legally required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IRS doesn't require 1099 to be filed for payments of less than $10. It is, however, taxable income.

The fact that 1099 wasn't filed with the IRS doesn't affect your tax liabilities.

If for example you have a private loan (say to a family member) and get paid interest on it, the payer will also probably not file 1099-INT with the IRS. However the interest you're being paid is taxable income to you and should be reported on Schedule B.

Comment: There's no need for schedule B unless your interest or dividends go over $1500.

Comment: @jonsca there are additional requirements to when Schedule B is required, not just the $1500. But in any case, even without Schedule B, you still put the amounts on your 1040 (line 8). I suggest always attaching schedule B - no harm in having it.