# Do I have to include a form 1099-INT with form 8938 even if I didn't earn any interest?

Tags: united-states, form-1099, foreign-income

I'm currently filling out [form 8938](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8938.pdf), "Statement of Specified Foreign Financial Assets", and have come to Part III:

[image]

Broadly speaking, there is an "Amount" column and a "Where reported" one. I have earned no interested, and according to [Do I include small amounts of interest on my taxes if they didn't send a 1099-INT?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29440/do-i-include-small-amounts-of-interest-on-my-taxes-if-they-didnt-send-a-1099-in) I don't have to report it. Can I therefore simply fill out "0.00" for (c) and leave (d) blank? Or do I have to file a form 1099-INT with only zeroes on it? (This is not clear to me from the [instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8938/ch02.html)).

Answer (score 1):

(Necro, but anyway)

As an individual taxpayer, you don't ever fill out 1099-INT, and you file a copy of it only in the very rare case backup withholding was applied to the interest payments you received (and not even then if you e-file).
And a foreign bank isn't required to (file and) send you 1099-INT even in situations where a US bank (or other financial institution) would.

When you do receive taxable interest, whether or not you received 1099-INT for it, you report that income in box 8a of 1040 or 1040A. If the total is over $1500 or certain other conditions apply -- and having a foreign account is one such condition -- you also fill out Schedule B with the individual item(s) and source(s). So if you *did* have interest you would point to Schedule B.

But since you *don't* have interest, you don't put anything here. Instead in Part V you check box 3d "No tax item reported in Part III for this asset".